# Can't put a second "with" statement into the query

Tags: sql, for-xml-path

I have a query - which is combining with a Union statement the 5 columns into 2 columns.
So basically - an ID + Some Information. As the ID could be in column 2-5 - several times... I rearranged to be everything in one ID column + the text.

Now - I wanted to use a second "with" statement - to combine the IDs of several rows - with a XML path. But here I got stuck.

That is the code - which gives me the two column - with content as expected:

```
    With
STall as (Select
    'Status: ' + ST.Status + Char(10) + 'Crew Information:' + Char(10) +
    'Instructor: ' + ST.IP + Char(10) + 'Student: ' + ST.SP + Char(10) + Case
      When ST.ACM1 = 'NA' Then '' Else 'ACM1: ' + ST.ACM1 + Char(10) End + Case
      When ST.ACM2 = 'NA' Then '' Else 'ACM2: ' + ST.ACM2 + Char(10)
    End + 'Lesson: ' + ST.Lesson + Char(10) + Case
      When ST.ScheduleRemarks = '' Then ''
      Else ' REM:' + ST.ScheduleRemarks + Char(10)
    End + 'Equipment: ' + ST.EquipmentName + ' (' + ST.Callsign + ')' +
    Char(10) + 'Start: ' + Convert(VARCHAR(10),ST.ScheduleTO,104) + ' - ' +
    Convert(VARCHAR(5),ST.ScheduleTO,108) + ' UTC' + Char(10) + 'End: ' +
    Convert(VARCHAR(10),ST.ScheduleTD,104) + ' - ' +
    Convert(VARCHAR(5),ST.ScheduleTD,108) + ' UTC' + Char(10) + Case
      When ST.ATC = 'NA' Then '' Else ST.ATC End As SInfo,
    ST.IDIP,
    ST.IDSP,
    ST.IDA1,
    ST.IDA2
  From
    (Select
      Case When Schedule.StatusRelease = 1 Then 'OK' Else Case
          When Schedule.StatusRequest = 1 Then 'STBY' Else 'N/A' End
      End As Status,
      Schedule.ContactIDIP,
      Schedule.ContactIDSP,
      MasterLesson.Lesson,
      Equipment.EquipmentName,
      CallSignList.Callsign,
      Schedule.Meeting,
      Schedule.ScheduleRemarks,
      Schedule.StatusRelease,
      Schedule.StatusRequest,
      Schedule.ScheduleDay,
      ContactList.FullNameTLC As IP,
      ContactList1.FullNameTLC As SP,
      Case When Schedule.ContactIDACM1 = 0 Then 'NA'
        Else ContactList2.FullNameTLC End As ACM1,
      Case When Schedule.ContactIDACM2 = 0 Then 'NA'
        Else ContactList3.FullNameTLC End As ACM2,
      Schedule.ScheduleTO,
      Schedule.ScheduleTD,
      Case When Schedule.RouteID = 0 Then 'NA'
        Else 'Route: ' + Airport.ICAO + ' - ' + Case
          When IsNull(Airport1.ICAO, 'NA') = 'NA' Then ' '
          Else Airport1.ICAO + ' - ' End + Airport2.ICAO + Char(10) + Char(13)
      End As ATC,
      ContactList.Id As IDIP,
      ContactList1.Id As IDSP,
      ContactList2.Id As IDA1,
      ContactList3.Id As IDA2
    From
      Schedule Inner Join
      StudentLesson On Schedule.ScheduleLessonID = StudentLesson.StudentLessonID
      Inner Join
      MasterLesson On StudentLesson.LessonID = MasterLesson.ID Inner Join
      Equipment On Schedule.EquipmentID = Equipment.ID Left Join
      CallSignList On CallSignList.ID = Schedule.CallSignListID Left Join
      Route On Route.ID = Schedule.RouteID Inner Join
      ContactList On ContactList.Id = Schedule.ContactIDIP Inner Join
      ContactList ContactList1 On ContactList1.Id = Schedule.ContactIDSP
      Left Join
      ContactList ContactList2 On Schedule.ContactIDACM1 = ContactList2.Id
      Left Join
      ContactList ContactList3 On Schedule.ContactIDACM2 = ContactList3.Id
      Left Join
      Airport On Route.AirportID_Dep = Airport.ID Left Join
      Airport Airport1 On Route.AirportID_Via = Airport1.ID Left Join
      Airport Airport2 On Route.AirportID_Arr = Airport2.ID
    Where
      ((Schedule.StatusRelease = 1) Or
        (Schedule.StatusRequest = 1)) And
      Schedule.ScheduleDay = '21.02.2014') As ST)

Select Distinct
  STall.IDIP,SInfo
From
  STall
where STall.IDIP > 0  

UNION
Select Distinct
  STall.IDSP,SInfo
From
  STall
where STall.IDSP > 0 
UNION
  Select Distinct
  STall.IDA1,SInfo
From
  STall
where STall.IDA1 > 0 
UNION
Select Distinct
  STall.IDA2,SInfo
From
  STall
  where STall.IDA2 > 0
```

Now - I tried to add another `With STtotal as (` in the beginning...
and

```
)
Select Distinct
  STsub.IDIP,
  SubString((Select
     +Char(10) + STn1.SInfo As [text()]
  From
    STsub STn1
  Where
    STn1.IDIP = STtotal.IDIP
  Order By
    STn1.IDIP
  For Xml Path('')), 2, 1000) ScheduleInfo
From
  STtotal
```

But I get an error - with wrong Statement at "with".

Maybe there is another approach - how to combine - the "Info Text" column with all IDs - which could be in column 2-5.

Thanks for any imput

Comment: Do you think it is possible to include a minimal testcase? Your code looks quite large to me ;-)

Comment: Are you trying to do two separate queries or use two CTEs in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your CTEs with a comma; the `WITH` only needs to be specified once:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
    ...
), CTE2 AS (
    ...
)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: well... I do not "union" the CTEs - I want to use the first as a sub-query... which will provide me the two columns - and than combine everything by ID.

Comment: The syntax I provided is how you specify multiple CTEs for use in a single query.  There is no inherent relationship among the CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to put a semi colon at the end of the first statement?